# How to perform a math operation on a column and then use that value in the where clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of users that have been active within the last 15 minutes from a modx database, the access field in the modx_session has a unix time of their last access. All I want to do is get all the users that have an access time of (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - us.access) less than 900 seconds:

here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - us.access) as last_access, u.id, u.username, ua.*, us.*, ux.*, u.id as id, ua.id as uaid, us.id as usid, ux.id as uxid 
FROM `modx_users` u 
LEFT JOIN `modx_user_attributes` ua ON ua.internalKey = u.id
LEFT JOIN `modx_gssi_user_ext_data` ux ON  ux.internalKey = u.id
LEFT JOIN `modx_session` us ON  us.id = ua.sessionid
WHERE ( ua.blocked = 0 AND u.active = 1 AND u.id != 1 AND last_access <= '900') 
ORDER BY u.id asc;
```

but I get an error:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'last_access' in 'where clause'
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont worry about using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - us.access` twice, MySQL's optimizer runs this expression only once.

```
SELECT 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - us.access) AS last_access,
    u.id,
    u.username,
    ua.*,
    us.*,
    ux.*,
    u.id AS id,
    ua.id AS uaid,
    us.id AS usid,
    ux.id AS uxid
FROM
    `modx_users` u
        LEFT JOIN
    `modx_user_attributes` ua ON ua.internalKey = u.id
        LEFT JOIN
    `modx_gssi_user_ext_data` ux ON ux.internalKey = u.id
        LEFT JOIN
    `modx_session` us ON us.id = ua.sessionid
WHERE
    (ua.blocked = 0 AND u.active = 1
        AND u.id != 1
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - us.access <= '900')
ORDER BY u.id ASC;
```